# Package array Error: Empty preamble: 'I' used (in table)

Tags: tables, tabularx

I draw a table using Latex, i tried many methods, delete and add, still have the error below [image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}ccccccccc}
        \toprule
% &  \small {\textbf{Mean (\%)}} 
& \multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Mean}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
& \multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Devia-} \\ \textbf{tion} \\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
& \multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error} \\ \textbf{Mean}  \\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
% & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference (\%)}}
& \multicolumn{2}{}{\makecell{\textbf{95\%}\\ \textbf{Confidence} \\ \textbf{Interval}  \\ \textbf{of the}  \\ \textbf{Difference (\%) }   }} 
& \multirow{3.5}{*}{\textbf{t}}
& \multirow{3.5}{*}{\textbf {df}} 
& \multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-} \\ \textbf{tailed)} }}  \\
\cmidrule{5-6}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
\midrule
    {Pair 1\tnote{a}} & 43.33 & 16.56 & 5.24 & 31.48  &  55.18 & 8.27 & 9 & 0.000\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is in `\multicolumn{2}{}{\makecell{\textbf{95\%}`, you need to add a column type, e.g. `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\textbf{95\%}`. Also a `tabularx` needs at least one `X` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from `\multicolumn{2}{}{\makecell{\textbf{95\%}...`. You cannot have an empty second argument there. In addition, `tabularx` makes only real sense if you have at least one `X` column. Here are two versions, one with an `X` column and one plain `tabular`. I also increased the first argument of `\multirow` to get rid of the `overfull \vbox` messages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*8{c}}
        \toprule
% % &  \small {\textbf{Mean (\%)}} 
& \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Mean}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Devia-} \\ \textbf{tion} \\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error} \\ \textbf{Mean}  \\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
% % & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference (\%)}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\textbf{95\%}\\ \textbf{Confidence} \\ \textbf{Interval}  \\ \textbf{of the}  \\ \textbf{Difference (\%) }   }} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{t}}
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf {df}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-} \\ \textbf{tailed)} }}  
\\
 \cmidrule{5-6}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
      & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
 \midrule
     {Pair 1\tnote{a}} & 43.33 & 16.56 & 5.24 & 31.48  &  55.18 & 8.27 & 9 & 0.000\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{10}c}
        \toprule
% % &  \small {\textbf{Mean (\%)}} 
& \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Mean}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Devia-} \\ \textbf{tion} \\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error} \\ \textbf{Mean}  \\ \textbf{(\%)}}} 
% % & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference (\%)}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\textbf{95\%}\\ \textbf{Confidence} \\
 \textbf{Interval}  \\ \textbf{of the}  \\ \textbf{Difference (\%)  }}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{t}}
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf {df}} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-} \\ \textbf{tailed)} }}  
\\
 \cmidrule{5-6}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
      & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
 \midrule
     {Pair 1\tnote{a}} & 43.33 & 16.56 & 5.24 & 31.48  &  55.18 & 8.27 & 9 & 0.000\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: car Thanks. brilliant! I didn't know that. Just one question, can you explain in simple words for `\begin{tabular}{c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}c*8{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}}` meaning?

Comment: @aan This was just me being stupid. What I should have done is to write `*{10}c`, which means that there are 10 columns of the type `c`. In general, `*{<n>}{<type>}` creates `n` columns of type `type`.